# trim a string in c#

Tags: c#, telerik, sitefinity

I'm taking pdf file names in telerik sitefinity like this :

```
test..pdf (41 KB )

1..pdf (34 KB )
```

How to change these like this? `test.pdf` and `1.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the extension is un-known, so in your case it's PDF, this simply can be done by:

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf","test..pdf (41 KB )".Split('.')[0]);
```

if you need more flexibility, can make `PDF` as string variable too.

Do not simply replace, as the file *can* contain points too.

Comment: I guess you meant extension, not exception?

Comment: I changed it to extension now.

Answer (score 2):

If they all look like this (two periods instead of one you could simply do:

```
myFileName = myFileName.Replace("..", ".");
```

Also it seems I didn't consider the size of the file that is appended to the path. That can be removed by splitting on the space, and taking the first element like this:

```
myFileName = myFileName.Split(' ')[0];
```

To obtain both the replacement of .. with . and remove the filesize, you can just chain them both together like this:

```
myFileName = myFileName.Replace("..", ".").Split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The String.Replace method would allow you to replace ".." with "." as long as you know there are no other cases where you may want ".."

EG:

```
 pdfFile = pdfFile.Replace("..", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

simpler: `string fileName = tempFileName.Replace("..pdf",".pdf");`

For performance, use `StringBuilder.Replace()` method,

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(tempFileName);
strBuilder.Replace("..pdf", ".pdf");
string fileName = strBuilder.ToString();
```

And if you're like me who only would want one instance replaced(this is slightly tricky)

```
string ReverseString(string p)
{
    char[] arr = p.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}

var regex = new RegEx("fdp..");
var fileName = ReverseString(regex.Replace(ReverseString(tempFileName), "fdp.",1));
```